# Convert my data to an object and pass it through to an asp.net MVC controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

The code works, but looking at it and the possibility it might need to grow concerns me.  Is it possible to package these 3 separate things into objects and pass them through to my MVC controller?

Prior to this update it was a simple array of strings that was being passed through.

I have to use `window.open()`  I've tried doing what I need done here using various other methods, but this is the only one that works.

Here is the code:

```
$('#print_quote').on('click', function (e) {
    debugger;
    // object one
    var ProgramDescription_0 = $('#pricing-box-0 .pricing-box .pricing-title h3').text();
    var PlanDescription_0 = $('#pricing-box-0 .pricing-box .pricing-title small').text();
    var RetailCost_0 = $('#pricing-box-0 .pricing-price span').text();
    var RateID_0 = $('#pricing-box-0 .pricing-price span').attr('id').replace('totalCost-', '');
    // object 2
    var ProgramDescription_1 = $('#pricing-box-1 .pricing-box .pricing-title h3').text();
    var PlanDescription_1 = $('#pricing-box-1 .pricing-box .pricing-title small').text();
    var RetailCost_1 = $('#pricing-box-1 .pricing-price span').text();
    var RateID_1 = $('#pricing-box-1 .pricing-price span').attr('id').replace('totalCost-', '');
    // object 3
    var ProgramDescription_2 = $('#pricing-box-2 .pricing-box .pricing-title h3').text();
    var PlanDescription_2 = $('#pricing-box-2 .pricing-box .pricing-title small').text();
    var RetailCost_2 = $('#pricing-box-2 .pricing-price span').text();
    var RateID_2 = $('#pricing-box-2 .pricing-price span').attr('id').replace('totalCost-', '');

    var url = '@Url.Action("PrintComparison", "Quote", new { selectedPlans = "__plans__" })';
    window.open(url.replace('__plans__', plans));
});
```

MVC Controller

```
public ActionResult PrintComparison(string ProgramDescription_0, string PlanDescription_0, string RetailCost_0, int RateID_0)
{
// Do stuff
}
```

Is it possible to turn these into objects and pass them through using `window.open` to my MVC controller awaiting them?

Comment: What is `plans` in you last line of code? And what is the signature of the `PrintComparison()` method?

Comment: Maybe using `ajax` should be more suitable, right?

Comment: @StephenMuecke plans is for the old way it was being used.  I filled plans with a simple array of strings and replaced it there in the final line.  Updating with MVC side.

Comment: I do not think that MVC will generate an object when calling your action if it is not called via POST

Comment: It unclear what your trying to do here. The values you sending are all `.text()` values (suggesting its non editable values in the view), so why are you sending back information that the server already knows?

Comment: @StephenMuecke This is going to an action that takes the data and runs it through Rotativa and turns it in a PDF for printing.  The original page has thousands and thousands of items, and I only need to send over 2-3 that were chosen for a comparison quote.  So rather than making them wait while I look through all of the data to pull out the 3, I was trying to simply pass over the relevant data.

Comment: In a word, no, you can't do what you describe. You could create JavaScript objects, serialize them as JSON, encode them into a URL, then  have your controller unencode them and deserialize them, but I think at that point you should be seriously considering a different architecture more along the lines of @Hackerman's suggestion of using ajax.

Comment: You would probably be better off just passing the ID's of the selected items and getting them again in the controller, but if you wanted to pass all the selected data, then you would need to generate the the names with indexers so the `DefaultModelBinder` can bind to a collection of your object - e.g. `[0].ProgramDescription`, `[0].PlanDescription` and the method would need a parameter `IEnumerable<yourModel>` where `yourModel` contains properties `ProgramDescription` etc.

Comment: But doing this as a GET is a bit risky - you could easily exceed the query string limit and a POST might be more appropriate (which also give you more options such as stringifying the data and using `contentType: 'json'`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

populate your array to pass;

```
var arr = [];
arr.push({
    ProgramDescription: "",
    PlanDescription: "",
    RetailCost: 0.00,
    RateID: -1
});
```

call your method via POST

```
$.post('@Url.Action("PriceComparision", "Quote")', arr, function(html){
     //use jqueryui Dialog Widget to display the resultant HTML
});
```

Comment: I think you mean `var arr = [];`? Otherwise the second line will fail...

Comment: It goes into my controller just fine, but, it then returns a 404 error for the actual page.  `return new ViewAsPdf("PrintComparison", model) { PageOrientation = Orientation.Landscape, PageSize = Size.Letter, CustomSwitches = pdfsettings };` is the line in the controller above.  Works just fine with window.open